# setRequestedOrientation cannot find symbol in react-native

Tags: java, android, react-native, orientation

I want to enable rotation only in tablets on Android. 
I Created bools.xml with this code

```
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and put in MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

    ...

    @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        super.onCreate();
     } 
  }
}
```

I get error: cannot find symbol
      **setRequestedOrientation**(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Answer (score 1):

Application doesn't have setRequestedOrientation() method — Activity does. So you should move the code into your BaseActivity onCreate().